# Jsf 1.2 to 2.0 ajax migration

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

We are migrating from Jsf 1.2 to 2.0 and having validation issues with drop down values updated through ajax using servlets.

What happens today is when a drop-down A is changed dropw-down B's values are fetched through ajax call using a servlet and in Jquery the drop-down values of B is changed based on the Ajax result but after migrating to JSF 2.0 we are getting invalid values issue for drop-down B when submitting the form because the updated drop-down values are not known to faces so wondering why it worked in JSF 1.1 but not 2.0. The bean is requestscoped

I know there is f:ajax with 2.0 but due to time constraint we are going to keep the servlets to make the ajax call if possible.

JSP

```
  <t:datalist value ='#{bean.locations}' var='loc'>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{loc.country}" onchange ='getStateListThroughServletAjax(this)'>
      <f:selectItems value ='#{loc.countryList}'/>
    </h:selectOneMenu> 
    <h:selectOneMenu id='states' value ='#{loc.state}'>
     <f:selectItems value='#{loc.stateList}'/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>  
  </t:datalist>
```

Javascript

```
function getStateListThroughServletAjax(country){
   //this get the Statelist based on country selected by hitting the servlet
   var params = 'countryId='+ country.value;
  $.ajax({type: "POST", url: '\loadStates',data: params,
     success: function(response) {
       jsonResult = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
       //setComboOptions for state dropwdown based on JsonResult
        setComboOptionsForState(jsonResult)
     }
    });
 }
```

Anytime i change the country i get a new statelist populated but while saving i get "Validation Error: Value is not valid ".

Any input is appreciated

Comment: Do you have any code  to show?

Comment: Preferably a [mcve]

Comment: updated with code

Comment: You xhtml will never work... _"value ='bean.locations'"_ is wrong...

Comment: Its still jsp not xhtml yet

Comment: Not releated to jsp or xhtml... It is (at least was untill you edited it) invalid EL. But what you seem to try (the implementation of setComboOptionsForState is very relevant but missing) is to add 'options' client side. That is not going to work for JSF (I think it did not even work in JSF 1.2) for security reasons. The server side has to know the valid options so the client cannot tamper with it. If you have good separation of concerns, switching from a servlet for the list to a managed bean should not be that difficult

Comment: It worked in 1.2 and even works in 2.0 as long as the bean is request scope but the problem is only when they are within t:datalist like in my jsp code..

Comment: Did yo update the `t:dataTable` (tomahawk?) to? Maybe **that** is the problem then... But then you at least also added them to "'#{loc.state}" as well... where? When? I'd personally suggest to switch to real JSF2 (2.2 at least preferably) Since you might encounter many other issue

Comment: We still want to use JSP's and f:ajax doesnt work in jsps. so would like to use the servlets

Comment: Is there still a way to accomplish this? i am not sure how it worked in jsf1.1 but not in 2.0